# How to recreate a Zip File from a MemoryStream

Tags: c#, azure, zip, azure-blob-storage, memorystream

I've looked around for a solution to my issue but no-one seems to being aiming for quite what I'm trying to achieve.

My problem is such, I have Zip files stored in Azure Blob storage, now for security's sake we have an API2 controller action that provisions these zip files, rather than allowing direct downloading.  This action will retrieve the blob, and download it to a stream, so that it can be packaged within a `HTTPResponseMessage`.

All of the above works, however, when I attempt to recreate the zip file, I'm informed it's corrupted.  For now I'm just attempting to have the server (running on localhost) create the zip file, whereas the endgame is to have remote Client applications do this (I'm fairly certain the solution to my issue on the server would be the same.

```
public class FileActionResult : IHttpActionResult 
{
  private HttpRequestMessage _request;
  private ICloudBlob _blob;

  public FileActionResult(HttpRequestMessage request, ICloudBlob blob)
  {
    _request = request;
    _blob = blob;
  }

  public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    var fileStream = new MemoryStream();
    await _blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(fileStream);

    var byteTest = new byte[fileStream.Length];
    var test = fileStream.Read(byteTest, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);

    try
    {
      File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\testPlatFiles\test.zip", byteTest);
    }
    catch(ArgumentException ex)
    {
      var a = ex;
    }

    var response = _request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
    response.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = _blob.Properties.Length;
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(_blob.Properties.ContentType);
    //set the fileName
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
      FileName = _blob.Name,
      Size = _blob.Properties.Length
    };
    return response;  
  }
}
```

I've looked into Zip libraries to see if any present the solution for converting the stream of a zip back to a zip file, but all I can find is reading zip files into streams, or the creation in order to provision a file download instead of a filecreate.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: does it depend on zip file size? if you try small zip file, less than a 1 Mb, do you still have issue? You may also try to do fileStream.ToArray() it will give you a byte[] arryay with content of your stream.

Comment: @AlexShapovalov Ok, so .ToArray() worked for me, basically my issue is that the filestream.Read is not working correctly, it writes the correct amount of bytes, but they all have a value of 0.  ToArray() creates the same sized Byte array, but bytes actually have values.  

My next issue is that on my client, the stream is a WebConnectionStream so turning it into a MemoryStream could be more troublesome, but I'll get on that now! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [`DotNetZip`](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). Its [`ZipFile`](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/547e4c24-4683-96df-036e-19bc34ba27e4.htm) class has a static factory method that should do what you want: [`ZipFile.Read( Stream zipStream )`](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/330b3e90-88f3-1c7a-c62f-aab90f198b82.htm) reads the given stream as a zip file and gives you back a `ZipFile` instance (which you can use for whatever.

However, if your `Stream` contains the raw zip data and all you want to do is persist it to disk, you should just be able to write the bytes straight to disk.

If you're getting 'zip file corrupted' errors, I'd look at the content encoding used to send the data to Azure and the content encoding it's sent back with. You should  be sending it up to Azure with a content type of `application/zip` or `application/octet-stream` and possibly adding metadata to the Azure blob entry to send it down the same way.

---

**Edited To Note:** DotNetZip used to live at Codeplex. Codeplex has been shut down. The old archive is still [available at Codeplex](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). It looks like the code has migrated to Github:

- https://github.com/DinoChiesa/DotNetZip. Looks to be the original author's repo.
- https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd. This looks to be the currently maintained version. It's also packaged up an available via Nuget at https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/

---

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I'll give DotNetZip a go tomorrow (was trying SharpZipLib and couldn't find what I was looking for).  As for the content type the upload stores the content type from the RequestMessage and it's then extracted from the Blob as you can see in the snippet, so it *should* be ok.

Comment: Marking as answer, as I've ended up needing to use DotNetZip portable in order to unzip from my file.

In the end it was blind stupidity on my part.  The filestream on the server (that is then being packaged as StreamContent) had it's position set to the end of the stream.  Setting it to 0 and my code worked perfectly.  I missed this because on my client consuming code, the position property isn't implemented so I wasn't able to evaluate it! 

Thank you.